# AdControl AdControl does not showing AD (MsPubCenter)

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-store-apps

I have created AdControl in my app. When I'm using test mode values from MSDN page. AD work well and is displayed, but when I insert `ApID` and `UnitID` from my PubCenter where I have my AD, AdControl  is not showing AD and im getting this error:

> An exception of type 'System.NotImplementedException' occurred in
>   'InstagramDownloader.Windows.exe' but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The method or operation is not implemented.

[image]

Edit

The exact error is : No ad available. I do not know why, in pubCenter ad is created and is active.

Comment: Delete the "throw new NotImplementedException();" from the ad_ErrorOccurred method an add real error handling code there.

Answer (score 0):

The application is throwing `NotImplementedException` as it is being instructed to do so. The code is telling the application to throw `NotImplementedException` inside the `ad_ErrorOccurred` method.

You need to include proper [error handling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/advertising-mobile-windows-phone-error-handling-ads%28v=msads.20%29.aspx) inside the `ad_ErrorOccurred` method for any error / exception information which is being passed into the method.

Not that this will remove all the errors, but this will give you a better understanding of what is the error/exception which occurred and you can take care of it.

Comment: I hooked up Error event handler with your advise and error is, that ad is not available but inn PubCenter i have created AD and Ad is active - http://oi60.tinypic.com/sc6jyw.jpg

Comment: The complet error message is just: No ad available.(i'm using e.Error.Message )